# Can we use any javascript framework to build maximo anywhere app

Tags: mobilefirst-studio, maximo-anywhere

Mobile First supports any javascript Framework like DOJO/Sencha/jQuery/AngularJS. So is it possible to build new maximo anywhere app also through any above mentioned JS Framework?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. The mentioned frameworks are frontend/client-side frameworks and as such have no relation to the functionality that MobileFirst and/or Maximo provide you with. They relate to how the app looks, not what the app does.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but, please understand you could have to rewrite some of the ANT scripts used to build the apps. I haven't attempted this yet, and would love to hear your feedback as to what you find. I'm not a fan of dojo and would like an alternative like ionic too!